# How to autowire service as constructor argument?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I have the following service:

```
public interface LogoutService {
    void logoutAllUsers();

    void dropUserSession(SessionInformation session);
}
```

and following implementation:

```
@Service
public class LogoutServiceImpl implements LogoutService {
    ...
```

---

```
public class MyXmlBean extends ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy {
    ....

       public MyXmlBean (MySessionRegistry sessionRegistry,
                                                              LogoutService logoutService) {
             ....
```

and following xml configuration:

```
<bean id="MyXmlBean" class="package.MyXmlBean">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="mySessionRegistry" />
    <constructor-arg name="logoutService" ref="logoutService"/>
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</bean>
```

When I start application - I see following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myXmlBean ' defined in class path resource [context-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myXmlBean ' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyXmlBean' defined in class path resource [context-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logoutService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'logoutService' is defined
```

How to fix it?

Comment: may sound trivial but is `context:component-scan` placed in your config as I can see this at end of error message `No bean named 'logoutService' is defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out

`@Service` annotation was imported from wrong package (non spring)